# Loading CSV into SQL Server error

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a SQL Server table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Service]
(
    [SID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [LID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [RID]     INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SID] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Service_dbo.Location_LID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([LID]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([LID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Service_dbo.Rates_RID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([RID]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Rates] ([RID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I have a `.csv` file that is literally 3 columns of ascending numbers that goes from 1-100000

Example:

```
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
```

and it goes on and on to 100k rows.

I am trying to load this `.csv` via T-SQL via Visual Studio with this query:

```
BULK INSERT service
FROM 'C:\service.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

I get the following error and I don't know why:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 3 (RID).

Comment: Shouldn't the row terminator be `\r\n`, since you're on Windows? WIndows uses carriage return and line feed (CRLF, or `\r\n`) as line terminators; *nix and OSX use LF (`\n`) only.

Comment: I thought that was the problem also but I tried with \r\n and it still gives the same error. I should add that I also gave '0x0a' a try also.

Comment: At least for a small example with three lines (`1...2...3`), your code seems to work fine. Have you tried seeing where exactly in the file it's failing?

Comment: Check the leading/trailing spaces in the csv file. According to the csv format any space (even after the comma) is part of the value

Comment: I have not checked where the line fails. Is there an easy way to check? I made the csv file through excel by creating one column and duplicating it 2 times.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), "Due to how Microsoft Windows treats text files (\n automatically gets replaced with \r\n)", their example uses `ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+'''`. BTW, you may wish to use KEEPIDENTITY option

Comment: Probably something is wrong with the csv. I would try: 1.create an "import table" without indexes, keys, allowing nulls, etc and pull in the csv there. If it goes fine (which btw is a better practice than going 'cold turkey' so to speak as you can _validate_ data before playing with a prod. table) then a few selects will tell you what's wrong (identical or null "SID" values, etc). And then 2. If it's not giving a satisfying result, cut the file in two and import one half. If that's OK, try the other half as well. If fails, cut in two the "wrong file" again and repeat (if was OK == key issue).

Comment: You can try load data via OPENROWSET, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662745/how-to-modify-data-in-csv-during-bulk-insert/35671570#35671570

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to diagnose issues with BULK INSERT is to specify an error file. The error file will contain the exact data from the failing row(s). Per MSDN, you will also get a control file that will identify each failing row and provide details about each failure.

```
    BULK INSERT service
    FROM 'C:\service.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
        ERRORFILE = 'C:\ErrorFile.txt'
    );
```

When you open the error file that contains the failing data, use a text editor that shows white space and non-printable characters or that has a display mode that will show the character code of each character. If you have any unexpected characters, they will show up.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Excel to save your CSV file then make sure that you have saved it as “CSV (MS-DOS)” not as “CSV (Macintosh)”. If the CSV file is the correct CSV file format then you can try to use a format file for the Bulk load.
The format file for you CSV should look as follow:

```
9.0
3
1   SQLINT  0   4   ","      1  SID ""
2   SQLINT  0   4   ","      2  LID ""
3   SQLINT  0   4   "\r\n"   3  RID ""
```

You can bulk load query will look as follow:

```
BULK INSERT [Service]
    FROM 'C:\import_dos.csv'
    WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\temp\services.FMT')
```